# Is there a way to automatically hide some search results?

Tags: browser-addons, search-engines

I'm looking for a way to hide some search results based on their address for example. I'm interested about a "permanent" way, not a query-based one (like "-stuffIdontWant").

I'm thinking about a browser extension which allows to fill a blacklist, but there are probably other ways.

Comment: By search results, you mean Google?

Comment: Are you talking about excluding certain keywords or blocking certain domains?

Comment: Yes, I meant Google, but I sometimes use other search engines, such as Qwant.
PS : You're right, this is clearly a duplicate... I don't know how I didn't see it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to install browser extensions:

- [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) (for Chrome)
- [Hide Unwanted Results of Google Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/) (for Firefox)